# Error unexpected '}] in "}" if else statement in R language

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm working on calculating Bond Value example in my Data Mining subject. I have problem with if else function. Here it is...

```
P<-1000 #original value - Menh gia trai phieu
T<-20 #maturity - Thoi han trai phieu - semi
r<-.06 #annual rate - Lai suat yeu cau
C<-30 #present value of coupons - Lai dinh ki

BV <- function(P,C,r,t,T){ #t = -th year
    #Find coupon Bon Value at time t mat T - Gia trai phieu
    tmat <- T-t # How many years have you get your bonds for?
    acrued <- C*2*t #already paid
    if(tmat != 0) { #include interim coupons
        i <- seq(1,2*tmat) #BVsemi - seq()=for loop
        acrued + sum(C/(1+r/2)^i) + P/(1+r/2)^(2*tmat)
    }else{ 
        acrued + P/(1+r/2)^(2*tmat) 
    }
}
```

The error message is:
**

```
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

**

I've already read all the topics that related to my problem but none of them works well...
Please show me the light in this problem...

Thank you

Hoang Anh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not reproduced. I copypasted your code, and did not receive any error.

```
> P<-1000 #original value - Menh gia trai phieu
> T<-20 #maturity - Thoi han trai phieu - semi
> r<-.06 #annual rate - Lai suat yeu cau
> C<-30 #present value of coupons - Lai dinh ki
> 
> BV <- function(P,C,r,t,T){ #t = -th year
+     #Find coupon Bon Value at time t mat T - Gia trai phieu
+     tmat <- T-t # How many years have you get your bonds for?
+     acrued <- C*2*t #already paid
+     if(tmat != 0) { #include interim coupons
+         i <- seq(1,2*tmat) #BVsemi - seq()=for loop
+         acrued + sum(C/(1+r/2)^i) + P/(1+r/2)^(2*tmat)
+     }else{ 
+         acrued + P/(1+r/2)^(2*tmat) 
+     }
+ }
>
```

Comment: If that's the case, don't answer. Instead, vote to close as "no mcve" or "non-reproducible".

Comment: @AndrewLi - there are no reasons "no mcve" or "non-reproducible" among the list of reasons to close.

Comment: Go to Off topic > 3rd or 4th option although the question's already been closed.

Comment: @user31264 what's the program you use? I'm using RGui version 3.3.2 64bit...
Do I need any pre-condition before running my script by Ctrl+R combination?

Comment: I've already solved my problem. I just need to grab the file.R and put it into RGui program, then it works well. 
Thank you ^^